# How to initialize 2d array using 1d arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code

```
int vertical[] = {0, 1};
int horizontal[] = {1, 0};
int diag1[] = {1, 1}, diag2[] = {1, -1};

int directions[][] = {vertical, horizontal, diag1, diag2};
```

Which gives me the following error on line 5:

```
Array has incomplete element type 'int []'
```

Thus, I'm stuck doing the following:

```
int directions[4][2] = {{0,1},{1,0},{1,1},{1,-1}};
```

How can I define `directions[][]` using the four 1d arrays?

Comment: How about C++ arrays: `std::array`? We are in 2021 with C++20 and people are still using C arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::array`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array vertical {0, 1};
    std::array horizontal {1, 0};
    std::array diag1 {1, 1}, diag2 {1, -1};

    std::array directions {vertical, horizontal, diag1, diag2};
    for (const auto dir : directions) {
        for (const auto val : dir) {
            std::cout << val << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```